# dojo datagrid change cell types on the fly

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is it possible to change the type of cell (i.e., from Select to Bool) in the cell of a data grid once the grid has been rendered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is support for this specific functionality, but you could try declaring both the bool and select in the structure of your grid, and choose to show or hide the appropriate column(grid.layout.setColumnVisibility) based on whatever your condition is for exchanging them.